# Router parameters

Tags: angular, routes

I have created an Angular Web site that allows users to register and to customize some elements of the web site (like images, contact etc...).

In my mind I see the changes users have to access the website using their name in the URL bar (if the user is registered with the user name "gianni" they have to reach the web site using `www.website.com/gianni`).

**My question is:**
How can I load my website in this way?
Of course all the pages have to include "gianni" (`www.website.com/gianni/contact` or `www.website.com/gianni/page`).

Comment: I improved the overall formatting of this question and also some spelling. I highlighted the question and some other key elements.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I guess is that once you know the "username" all you need to do is navigate to the URL you want

```
this.router.navigate(['gianni']);
```

I guess your code will look something like this:

```
export class MySomethingComponent {
    constructor(
    private router: Router)
{}

goToSomePerson(username:string){
   this.router.navigate(['/'+ username]);
 }
```

Where `goToSomePerson` will be invoked when needed.

The above of course is assuming that your routing is properly created:

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
   {path:':username',component:SomeOtherComponent }
]
```

Comment: But I don't know the user name: it depens on the user, it may be "gianni" or "perla" or whatever, the website should load the same page "www.mywebsite.com/username" for every username

Comment: The user name is a url parameter, and once I load "www.mywebsite.com/username" every page should be "www.mywebsitelcom/username/page"

Comment: It is stored somewhere for sure in your application if not then start by doing so

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to build up the routing of your app. Let's say your app will have this routing structure:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
path: ':userUniqueId',
component: RootComponent,
children: [{
  path: 'contact',
  loadChildren: () => import('./containers/contact/contact.module').then(m => m.ContactModule),
}, {
  path: 'page',
  loadChildren: () => import('./containers/page/page.module').then(m => m.PageModule),
}]
}]
```

Now depending on a needs of your app you can add a guard in root path to fetch a user data, save it in store/memory/service/etc and reuse for feature needs